# Text widget doesn't ellipsis correctly in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

- I am trying to create a list view that contains 10 data, in each item there four widgets that wraps inside a row.
- First i inserted a circle image widget, in next I added expanded widget to divide the text widgets equally.
- Almost, I have achieved but i found difficulty in ellipsis the text.

**Code**

```
class EmailPage extends StatefulWidget {
    @override
    _EmailPageState createState() => _EmailPageState();
    }

class _EmailPageState extends State<EmailPage> {
  GlobalKey _keyRed = GlobalKey();
  var name = "Adellena Jacksonnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn";
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          elevation: 0.0,
          backgroundColor: greenColor,
          title: const Text('Inbox'),
          actions: <Widget>[
            new IconButton(
              icon: new Icon(Icons.edit),
              onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(null),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        body: SizedBox(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          child: ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: 10,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                  child: new Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 30,
                        height: 30,
                        child: CircleAvatar(
                            backgroundColor: Colors.brown.shade800),
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        child: new Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Expanded(
                                flex: 4,             
                                child: Container(
                                  child: new Text(
                                          name,
                                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                          softWrap: false,
                                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
                                        ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                            new Expanded(
                              flex: 3,
                              child: new Text(
                                "&14215",
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),

                              ),
                            ),
                            new Expanded(
                              flex: 3,
                              child: new Text(
                                "1000 min ago",
                                textAlign: TextAlign.end,
                                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              }),
        ));
  }
}
```

**Screenshot 1**

[image]

> When we remove `overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis` in the text widget look like this [Screenshot 2]

**Screenshot 2**

[image]

> In above image i didn't get the full text "AdellenaJacksonnnnnnnnn
>   ", but **expanded restrict the widget
>   how many flex can be shown in it. Problem is ellipsis not working as
>   expected**

**Note : When i remove the space in the string `var name = "AdellenaJacksonnnnnnnnn";` like this ellipsis working fine**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`overflow: TextOverflow.fade` did the trick for me.

Comment: It does produces a better result indeed

Answer (score 31):

The **simplest** way:

```dart
var name = 'Adellena Jacksonnnnnnnnn';
name = name.replaceAll('', '\u200B');
```

[image]

For simpler to use, you can write an **extension**:

```dart
extension StringExtension on String {
  String useCorrectEllipsis() {
    return replaceAll('', '\u200B');
  }
}
```

usage:

```dart
final name = 'Adellena Jacksonnnnnnnnn'.useCorrectEllipsis();
```

Comment: Thanks this works great, but I wonder how expensive this is if you do this on 50 to 100 items

Comment: what is this? Can you be kind to give me some information about this solution?

Comment: thanks, very simple solution. can you add some explanation about this answer?

Comment: Hi, @Nazar \u200B means Zero width space characters, it's a special space you can't see but would act as normal space.

Comment: same, source https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/18761#issuecomment-812390920

Comment: This worked great. I found it also visually increased the spacing between letters in my case, so I did something like `style: bodyText1?.apply(letterSpacingFactor: .5)` to offset it.

Answer (score 8):

You could make use of this stupid hack, by splitting the name into, you could modify and actually make use of it if you set any max length for first name.

I have clipped the first name so it won't look like it's overflowing get along with the ui, assume there is no maxlength

```
Flexible(
 child: Text(
 tempname[0],
 overflow: TextOverflow.clip,
 maxLines: 1,
 ),
),
```

The last name is set ellipsis to give a hit the name is overflowing

```
Flexible(
 child: Text(
 tempname[0],
 overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
 ),
),


ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: 10,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                var tempname = name.split(' ');
                return Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                  child: new Row(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 30,
                        height: 30,
                        child: CircleAvatar(
                            backgroundColor: Colors.brown.shade800),
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        child: new Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Expanded(
                              flex: 4,
                              // width: 100,
                              child: Row(
                                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Flexible(
                                    child: Text(
                                      tempname[0],
                                      overflow: TextOverflow.clip,
                                      maxLines: 1,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Text(' '),
                                  Flexible(
                                    child: Text(
                                      tempname[1],
                                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                    ),
                                  )
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                            new Expanded(
                              flex: 3,
                              child: new Text(
                                "&14215",
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                              ),
                            ),
                            new Expanded(
                              flex: 3,
                              child: new Text(
                                "1000 min ago",
                                textAlign: TextAlign.end,
                                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              }),
```

name = 'Adellenaddddddddddddd Jacksoonnnnnnnnnn';
[image]

name = 'Nadeem Jacksoonnnnnnnnnn';

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try with flexible instead of Expanded because. [Official Documentation](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Flexible-class.html)

> Using a Flexible widget gives a child of a Row, Column, or Flex the flexibility to expand to fill the available space in the main axis (e.g., horizontally for a Row or vertically for a Column), but, unlike Expanded, Flexible does not require the child to fill the available space.

Comment: Is this will work ?? .. what will be the difference

Answer (score 0):

try to type the surname seperated like that jackson nn nn nnn nnn that will work better

Comment: Yes i tried it out, it seems works but why i doesn't work when i left one space in between the strings

Comment: because it looks like a block of string otherwise in seperated type they looks like couple of words